# SWI-Prolog dynamic/1 vs dynamic/2

Tags: prolog, prolog-directive-dynamic

I am teaching myself Prolog and have been given a handful of examples.

One of which uses the `dynamic/1` built-in directive:

```
:- dynamic(items/1).
```

I get the idea of dynamic. That one can modify predicates via the assert, and retract predicates.

However, the program also uses the following in places:

```
:- dynamic(location/2).
```

What is the difference between the two /1 and /2, is their also a /3 .... /n?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Prolog, predicates are identified by their name (or functor) **and** their number of arguments (or arity). Thus, `items/1` denotes a predicate with functor `items` and arity `1` while `location/2` denotes a predicate with functor `location` and arity `2`. Two predicates with the same functor but different arities are different predicates.

Comment: Perfect answer and too the point. I get it entirely now. Thanks.